# Ordering a nested dictionary by the frequency of the nested value

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

I have this `list` made from a csv which is massive.
For every item in `list`, I have broken it into it's `id` and `details`. `id` is always between 0-3 characters max length and `details` is variable.
I created an empty dictionary, D...(rest of code below):

```
D={}

for v in list:

    id = v[0:3]
    details = v[3:]

    if id not in D:
        D[id] = {}

    if details not in D[id]:
        D[id][details] = 0

    D[id][details] += 1
```

aside: Can you help me understand what the two `if` statements are doing? *Very new to python and programming.*

Anyway, it produces something like this:

```
{'KEY1_1': {'key2_1' : value2_1, 'key2_2' : value2_2, 'key2_3' : value2_3},
'KEY1_2': {'key2_1' : value2_1, 'key2_2' : value2_2, 'key2_3' : value2_3},
and many more KEY1's with variable numbers of key2's
```

Each 'KEY1' is unique but each 'key2' isn't necessarily. The `value2_
s` are all different.

Ok so, right now I found a way to sort by the first KEY

```
for k, v in sorted(D.items()):
    print k, ':', v
```

I have done enough research to know that dictionaries can't really be sorted but I don't care about sorting, I care about ordering or more specifically frequencies of occurrence. In my code `value2_x` is the number of times its corresponding `key2_x` occurs for that particular `KEY1_x`. I am starting to think I should have used better variable names.

Question: How do I order the top-level/overall dictionary by the number in `value2_x` which is in the nested dictionary? I want to do some statistics to those numbers like...

1. How many times does the most frequent KEY1_x:key2_x pair show up?
2. What are the 10, 20, 30 most frequent KEY1_x:key2_x pairs?

Can I only do that by each `KEY1` or can I do it overall? Bonus: If I could order it that way for presentation/sharing that would be very helpful because it is such a large data set. So much thanks in advance and I hope I've made my question and intent clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to order the key pairs based on their frequency. It also provides an easy way to get x most frequent items:

```
from collections import Counter

d = {
    'KEY1': {
        'key2_1': 5,
        'key2_2': 1,
        'key2_3': 3
    },
    'KEY2': {
        'key2_1': 2,
        'key2_2': 3,
        'key2_3': 4
    }
}

c = Counter()
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    c.update({(k, k1): v1 for k1, v1 in v.iteritems()})

print c.most_common(3)
```

Output:

```
[(('KEY1', 'key2_1'), 5), (('KEY2', 'key2_3'), 4), (('KEY2', 'key2_2'), 3)]
```

If you only care about the most common key pairs and have no other reason to build nested dictionary you could just use the following code:

```
from collections import Counter

l = ['foobar', 'foofoo', 'foobar', 'barfoo']
D = Counter((v[:3], v[3:]) for v in l)
print D.most_common() # [(('foo', 'bar'), 2), (('foo', 'foo'), 1), (('bar', 'foo'), 1)]
```

**Short explanation**: `((v[:3], v[3:]) for v in l)` is a [`generator expression`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) that will generate `tuples` where first item is the same as top level key in your original `dict` and second item is the same as key in nested `dict`.

```
>>> x = list((v[:3], v[3:]) for v in l)
>>> x
[('foo', 'bar'), ('foo', 'foo'), ('foo', 'bar'), ('bar', 'foo')]
```

`Counter` is a subclass of `dict`. It accepts an `iterable` as an argument and each unique element in `iterable` will be used as key and value is the count of element in the `iterable`.

```
>>> c = Counter(x)
>>> c
Counter({('foo', 'bar'): 2, ('foo', 'foo'): 1, ('bar', 'foo'): 1})
```

Since `generator expression` [is an iterable](http://nvie.com/posts/iterators-vs-generators/) there's no need to convert it to list in between so construction can simply be done with `Counter((v[:3], v[3:]) for v in l)`.

The `if` statements you asked about are checking if the key exists in `dict`:

```
>>> d = {1: 'foo'}
>>> 1 in d
True
>>> 2 in d
False
```

So the following code will check if key with value of `id` exists in dict `D` and if it doesn't it will assign empty dict there.

```
if id not in D:
    D[id] = {}
```

The second `if` does exactly the same for nested dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for replying - I see that it produces a list but the values I care about are still stuck inside a dictionary right? I'd like to know the most frequent occurrences of KEY:key pairs. Thanks for the second explanation though - I think I understand - does D[id] create a dictionary with the `key` being 'id' and the `value` blank? Not sure about the second if statement.

Comment: @nrksj I've updated the answer based on the clarification.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I played around with your solution and think it should work for my actual data set. I don't know what motivates people like you to help us newbies but I appreciate it. Right now it feels like magic and I will do some more reading into your code but any comments/explanation you can add would be wonderful. Marking this answered. @niemmi

Comment: @nrksj You're welcome! I added an explanation, hope it helps.